# Post loop data not resetting on exit (I suspect)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Custom Post with custom meta boxes being displayed in the admin_notices area. Everything renders and styles correctly, no issues there BUT..... When adding a new regular post, or post of type page, or the new custom post type; the title and content and slug are pre-populated, not blank for me to fill in. If I change the title/content it saves as a new post. I've removed chunks of code and it only goes away when I remove the below function. I went as far as rebuilding it from the official [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) documentation w/o success.

Example: Image shows after clicking new page, it pulls in the title/content/slug for display. If I replace the title/content the new page will save with the correct content and slug, it just seems to be being pulled into the display.

[new post after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nfkt.jpg)

```
function dd_admin_notice_loop_display() {

  $dd_admin_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'dd-admin-notice', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

  if ( $dd_admin_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $dd_admin_all_query->have_posts() ) : $dd_admin_all_query->the_post();
       $class = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'ddadminalert', true ); ?>
         <li><?php echo '<div class="dd-notice notice ', print $class; ?> "><span class="dd-admin-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span><span class="dd-admin-content"><?php the_content(); ?></span></div></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); 
    else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif;
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'dd_admin_notice_loop_display');
```

Comment: Your `WP_Query` is *outside* your `if` but you are calling ` wp_reset_postdata();` *inside* the `if` (and not the `else`)... that will mean the post data isn't getting cleared in some circumstances anyway. But whether it's the reason you the bug you see, I'm not sure.